# nuget: constrain version when installing to version already in local repository

Tags: nuget

When doing "install-package", nuget will get the latest version from the package source. If I want to constrain the selected version I need to explicitly set the version number. Is there a way to tell nuget to resolve the version from the local packages already installed in the solution?

Example:

```
package in solution packages folder:
Castle.Core.3.2.0

install-package castle.Core -projectname SomeProjectRequiringCastle
```

This will download the newest version of Castle (3.3.0), and add it to my packages folder. This is not what I want to do 99% of the time. In order to constrain nuget to select the version number already installed I have to remember the already installed version number:

```
install-package castle.Core -projectname SomeProjectRequiringCastle -version 3.2.0
```

My current workflow includes browsing to the packages folder to see whats already installed or opening a packages.config file from a project which already has a dependency on the requested assembly. Ideally I want something like this:

```
install-package castle.Core -localRepositoryVersion
```

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour? Or perhaps some nifty commands which can make my workflow around this a bit smoother? Note: The "manage" option under the nuget package manager (GUI) is to mouse-heavy and has already been rejected by my mouse-allergic fingers.

## Edit

I wrapped Matts answer (credit to Matt, thanks) up in a function, here is a full solution for the lazy ones:

installLocal.psm1

```
<#
.Synopsis
    Installs a package
#>

function install-local
{

    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
            [String] $Id,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
            [string]$ProjectName
        )

        $version = get-package | ? { $_.Id -eq $Id } | % { $_.Version }

        if (-not $version) {
            throw "A package with id $Id has not been installed in the solution"
        } else {
            write-host "Found version: $version of $Id installed in solution"
        }

        install-package -Id $Id -ProjectName $ProjectName -Version $version
}

export-modulemember -function install-local
```

Added this line to the powershell profile used by visual studio (which in my case was located at: C:\Data\WindowsPowerShell\NuGet_profile.ps1)

```
import-module <path to file>\installLocal.psm1
```

Then I can write one-liners from the package manager console:

```
PM> install-local moq -projectname LibWhichNeedsDeps
Found version: 4.0.10827 of moq installed in solution
'Moq 4.0.10827' already installed.
Adding 'Moq 4.0.10827' to LibWhichNeedsDeps.
Successfully added 'Moq 4.0.10827' to LibWhichNeedsDeps.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use the Get-Package command. This lists all the packages installed in the solution.

So you could something similar to:

```
$version = Get-Package | where-object { $_.Id -eq 'NUnit' } | % { $_.Version }
Install-Package NUnit -version $version
```

You can turn this into a function and add it to your profile. That would allow you to use a one line command instead of typing all of it in each time. You would want to add some error checking if there is no package that is already installed using that package id.

Another approach would be to just run Get-Package, copy the version you need from the output, then run the Install-Package command with the version number.